# How can I determine the time taken outside a web service that can extend its response time

Tags: java, rest, soap, timeout, weblogic

I have a SOAP web service that consumes another REST service both requests are made with an Executor - SingleThreadExecutor and both have different timeouts. I log the time taken by every request and that time does not reach the timeout setted. My problem begins once I stress out the service. the requests takes more time than the time setted on the timeouts and ends in response times longer than the timeout. I need to know where does the webservice or the application server forms up the requests or what can be the reason of that wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally run into an answer, personally I'm working with weblogic and into this application server we count with an utility called Monitoring Dashboard. this is located in the main page of the console, inside the Graphics submenu, there we can see the number of threads used, free and hogged. Also weblogic settings counts with something called WorkManager, if we don't specify a workmanager (eather by the weblogic.xml or directilly on the administration console) weblogic uses its own default WM, this workManager queues the requests while it founds a free thread that can answer that request. To avoid this is necesary specify a workmanager that increases the number of free threads that are created once we deploy the web service. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13714/dashboard.htm#WLDFC431
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/self_tuned.htm